# Show Pop-ups and Highlight on Hover in Qgis2web when organizing layers into groups

Tags: popup, html, qgis2web

I have exported a web map in Open Layers using the last version of Qgis2web and I have modified the layers.js in order to grouped the layers:

var layersList = [

new ol.layer.Group({

```
        title: 'Infraestructura General', 

        fold: 'open', 

        layers: [lyr_puntosdeprovincias_4,
```

new ol.layer.Group({

```
        title: 'RSU', 

fold: 'open', 

        layers: [
```

lyr_Merged_3,

]}),

]}),

new ol.layer.Group({

```
        title: 'Rutas', 

        fold: 'open', 

        layers: [
```

lyr_Autopistas_1,lyr_mardis_redferrocarril_nacional_2014_0,

]}),

new ol.layer.Group({

```
        title: 'Edificios', 

        fold: 'open', 

        layers: [
```

lyr_MovilidadYTransporteRedesAcceso_GobiernosLoca_7boBXd4_2,

]}),

];

[image]

But when grouping the layers the pop ups and highlight on Hover no longer work, so I tried modifying in the gis2web.js the following lines, but it still doesn't work. I'm not sure if I'm changing the correct words or lines. I have changed the word layer to layer.Group but it still doesn't work.
These are the lines I have changed in both var onPointerMove and var onSingleClick respectively:

map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {

```
    if (layersList.indexOf(layer) === -1) { 

        return; 

    } 

    var doPopup = false; 

    for (k in layer.get('fieldImages')) { 

        if (layer.get('fieldImages')[k] != "Hidden") { 

            doPopup = true; 

        } 

    } :
```

and

```
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    if (layer && feature instanceof ol.Feature && (layer.get("interactive") || layer.get("interactive") == undefined)) {
        var doPopup = false;
        for (k in layer.get('fieldImages')) {
            if (layer.get('fieldImages')[k] != "Hidden") {
                doPopup = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: An update dedicated to layer groups will be released soon, which also fixes this bug.  I think I can do it within 2 weeks.  If you are happy with qgis2web, consider donating a virtual coffee via the button on the github home to support development.